# Using Visual Studio code, coding vb.net, how can I start my program then enter debug mode?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-code

I need to make my development portable, I'm mostly used to just using excel as a vba IDE but I started making the switch to visual studio big edition

Unfortunately, installing VS big edition is far too heavy to ask of random IT departments wherever I go so I need to go portable, I'm switching to VS code

Lots of things are different but I miss this feature dearly, perhaps it is not in VS code at all ?

In well, VB6 IDE I could hit F5 and it would compile my exe and run it
Then at any time I could his CTRL+BREAK to drop in debut mode.

I could see, what line was presently executing, I could move the cursor to a different place in the code. I could even edit the code, at least -some- things. I could hit F8 to execute only one step of code  and I'm sure there were tons more feature to that debugger that I never learned (something about watch variables ?)  oh yeah, and there was a console that I could just type code into and it would just execute it like it was part of the code like

```
print myvalue
```

or

```
 getsession.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

It was wonderful, can I get this in VS Code ?

thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio Code uses extensions to support debugging of different programming languages:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

However, if you're coding in VB, I highly suggest installing Visual Studio instead. It's worth the hassle.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to be portable because I often end up needing to tweak my program on the go on random work computers in random companies and getting IT to install custom software is making this impossible.    Using the page you linked I found the "install additional debuggers", looks like they have everything but vb.net :\

Comment: @Shodan I'm sorry to hear that. Maybe you can look for other (portable) IDE's that support VB.NET debugging.